# Adjoining adjoints in a 2-category

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

For a given 2-category $C$, does there exist a faithful and locally faithful 2-functor $C \to C^*$, such that the image of every 1-morphism of $C$ has a right adjoint in $C^*$?

Below are some of my thoughts. Although I'll be happy to other ideas too.

There are two ways which I believe give a (not very explicit) construction of a right adjoint adjoining 2-functor. As far as I can see both give the universal such 2-functor, so there should be an isomorphism between them.

1) To construct $C^*$, first take an underlying 2-graph of $C$. Consider it as a 2-computad, and add to it 1-cells which will be the right adjoints, and 2-cells which will be units and counits for the adjunctions. Then take the free 2-category on the resulting 2-computad, and factor it out by an appropriate congruence, which comes from the structure of the original 2-category and the triangle equalities. There is an obvious $C \to C^*$.

2) Let $C_0$ be the underlying 1-category of $C$. Take the universal right adjoint adjoining 2-functor $C_0 \to C'$. The explicit construction of $C'$ is in

R. J. M. Dawson, R. Paré, D. A. Pronk, Adjoining adjoints, Advances inbMathematics 178 (2003), pp. 99-140.

Then let $C^*$ be the pushout of $C \leftarrow C_0 \to C'$ in 2-Cat. We obtain $C \to C^*$.

The question is whether $C \to C^*$ is faithful and locally faithful.

It is shown in the three author paper that $C_0 \to C'$ is faithful and locally faithful. So in (2) we are taking a pushout of faithful and locally faithful 2-functors.

The same question can be considered in which one wants to adjoin adjoints only to a given class of 1-morphisms of $C$.

Answer (score 2):

I think, that under some mild conditions, there is a more natural and explicit construction (I am writing this off the top of my head, you have to carefully check my statements). The idea is that "adjoining a right adjoint to a morphism, makes the morphism a relation".

First, let us consider an easier (1-dimensional) case, when $\mathbb{C}$ is 2-discrete. If $\mathbb{C}$ is regular, then there is a faithful functor:
$$\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathit{Rel}(\mathbb{C})$$
that embeds $\mathbb{C}$ into its 2-posetal category of internal relations $\mathit{Rel}(\mathbb{C})$ and has the property that the image of every morphism has a right adjoint (in fact the converse is also true --- if a morphism in $\mathit{Rel}(\mathbb{C})$ has a right adjoint, then it comes from $\mathbb{C}$).

An internal relation in $\mathbb{C}$ is a span of morphisms $A \leftarrow R \rightarrow B$, where the legs are jointly monic. If we take a pushout of such a span, then we obtain a cospan representation of a relation. A 2-dimensional analogue of an internal relation is a codiscrete cofibred cospan.

So, let us assume, that $\mathbb{C}$ is a *cofibrational* 2-category. Then one may consider the 2-category $\mathit{Mod}(\mathbb{C})$ of codiscrete cofibred cospans in $\mathbb{C}$ with the (co)fibrational composition (i.e. the dual of discrete fibred spans in $\mathbb{C}^{op}$). There is an embedding:
$$\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathit{Mod}(\mathbb{C})$$
sending a morphism $f \colon A \rightarrow B$ to the cocomma cospan (i.e. collage) over $A \overset{id}\leftarrow A \overset{f}\rightarrow B$ which has a right adjoint in $\mathit{Mod}(\mathbb{C})$.

(If $\mathbb{C}$ is *fibrational*, one may also consider the dual construction --- the embedding of $\mathbb{C}$ into the 2-category $\mathit{DFib}(\mathbb{C})$ of discrete fibred spans in $\mathbb{C}$.)

Comment: I think I remember Jeffrey Morton telling me something similar --- that for an n-category C, the category of Spans in C (or perhaps spans of spans, k times) is the universal n-category receiving a functor from C in which every morphism is (k-) dualizable.  If I have misremembered this, then it is entirely my fault, and not Jeffrey's.

Comment: This construction is only universal under additional constraint (Beck-Chevalley), as explained in the paper cited in the question (btw here is the [link](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0001870802000683/1-s2.0-S0001870802000683-main.pdf?_tid=e813aa5e-a9a3-11e3-a55a-00000aacb361&acdnat=1394600899_c15186da9b8f78b9f1b22fc25d04d025))

Comment: This is another, in a way more conceptual approach. However it works only when some conditions are imposed on C. In addition, "(co)fibrational composition" usually is not strictly associative. Or is there a strict 2-category Mod(C) when C is a strict 2-category?

Comment: A generalization of the universal adjoint adding construction for a bicategory C is announced in the cited paper. It also says that the construction would give a strict 2-category when the original C is strict. But I don't know if anything has been published yet.

Comment: @DimitriChikhladze, you may always strictify a weak 2-category to a strict 2-category, however, I think for $\mathit{Mod}(\mathbb{C})$ there should be a (simple) canonical choice of an equivalent strict 2-category. I will come to this comment later, when time allows...

Comment: Yes, that's one thing one could do, although strictification is up to biequivalence, which may not be strictly faithful.

Comment: On the other hand one may think of building some sort of strict Mod(C) in analogy with the Rel construction. The morphisms of Rel(C) are not quite jointly monic spans, but rather isomorphism classes of these. I wonder whether something like this can be done with fibratoins.